# Concatenate two string and convert to datetime pandas python

Tags: python-3.x, date, csv, datetime, pandas

I am using latest version of pandas and python 3.5

I have  a CSV file with two columns `DATE` and `TIME` both are string

```
DATE: 07Jan2015
TIME: 0:00:00
```

I need to concatenate `DATE` and `TIME` and convert the result to datetime or timestamp but the DATE must be in following format

```
DATE FORMAT: 01/07/2015
```

So the result should look like this:

```
01/07/2015 0:00:00
```

I am using pandas to import the CSV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
print (df)
        DATE     TIME
0  07Jan2015  0:00:00
1  08Jan2015  1:00:00

df['NEW'] = pd.to_datetime(df.DATE + df.TIME, format='%d%b%Y%H:%M:%S')
df['NEW'] = df.NEW.dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')

print (df)
        DATE     TIME                  NEW
0  07Jan2015  0:00:00  01/07/2015 00:00:00
1  08Jan2015  1:00:00  01/08/2015 01:00:00
```

[Python's strftime directives](http://strftime.org/).